# How to generate the images sequence for video

Tags: image, video, image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick

I want to make a simple video editor to create the video from some images.
It have some transform effects such as motion, scale, fade etc...

I tried to create the images per frame using ImageMagick and create the video using ffmpeg.

But it doens't move smoothly, seems to be kind of jaggy when it moves.

For example, for 10s x 30fps video, it needs 300 images. Source image should to move 300px.

The image in the result video moved 1px by 1px.

How to generate the images sequence for smooth motion effect to make a video?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Show your code and also show examples please

Answer (score 0):

Here is the brief extract of my code.

```
$fps = 30;
$duration = 5;
$y1 = 0; $y2 = 90;
$frames = $fps * $duration;
for ($i = 0; $i < $frames; $i++) {
    $y = $y1 + ($y2 - $y1) * $i / $frames;
    $im = new Imagick("1.png");
    $im->resizeImage(800, 600, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, false); 
    $im->cropImage(640, 360, 0, $y);
    $im->setImagePage(640, 360, 0, 0);
    $im->writeImage(sprintf("tmp/%05d.jpg", $i + 1));
}

$cmd = sprintf("ffmpeg -f image2 -i %s/tmp/%%5d.jpg -r %d -pix_fmt yuv420p -y %s/tmp/result.mp4", dirname(__FILE__), $fps, dirname(__FILE__));
exec ($cmd);
```

And here are the links of the video I desire and the result video I made.

Sample video I desire: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6ewanf3zfk1bd6/sample.mp4

Result video I made:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/4skvlbv8iwgyf1d/movie.mp4